# Find a get queryset values that existes in another queryset of tha same model

Tags: django, django-models

Iam tring filter permission queryset that exists in another Queryset of permission.
How can filter that Queryset

####### My code

```
staff_perm = instance.permissions.all().
designation_perms = instance.designation.permissions.all()

# needed_designation_perms = designation_perms that exists in staff_perm
```

Ex :
Consider A and B are Querysets

```
A = [1,2,3,4,5]
B = [1,3,5,7,9]

i want 

C = [1, 3, 5]
here C values from 'A' and values from 'B that exists in A'
```

Comment: The example you provided isn't clear.

Comment: C values from 'A' and values from 'B that exists in A'

Comment: @ShiBilPK The values from A and values from B that exist in A would just be A as you describe it, no? Is your example correct or do you want `C = [1, 3, 5]`?

Comment: @IainShelvington yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the expected values are unique, then you can try this(compare across sets):

```
C = list(set(A).intersection(set(B)))
```

**Update 09.12.2022**

Try [intersection()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/). replace your_model with the name of your model and replace the fields 'field1', 'field2' with your own.

```
staff_perm = your_model.objects.values('field1')
designation_perms = your_model.objects.values('field2')
print(staff_perm.intersection(designation_perms))
```

Comment: I need same with queryset. not list, is this work for queryset. Please consider my examble as a queryset (model instances)

Answer (score 0):

It would be possible if you could iterate it through the for loop:

```
for x in desig_permission:
    if x in staff_permission:
        #DO SOMETHING like add to a list
    else:
        pass
```

Comment: Is there any other way without iterate?

Comment: Umm. I am not getting any other ones on my mind rn.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).